# .NET Core Azure Web App An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a multiple project solution running perfectly fine in 'Start without debugging' locally.

After publishing a .NET Core multiple project solution to an Azure Web App the very first http client setup falls over and produces the following error -

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions

The call to one of the web api's within the solution

```
httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44311/api/")
            };
```

Is making the error.

The full stack is below -

```
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
StoreFrontWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Really appreciate any tips?

Comment: Well, you can't host an API on `localhost:44311` in Azure App Service. Most likely this URL should be like `https://appname.azurewebsites.net/api/`?

Answer (score 0):

@juunas is right. From the official doc:

> The only way an application can be accessed via the internet is
>   through the already-exposed HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) TCP ports;
>   applications may not listen on other ports for packets arriving from
>   the internet. However, applications may create a socket which can
>   listen for connections from within the sandbox. For example, two
>   processes within the same app may communicate with one another via TCP
>   sockets; connection attempts incoming from outside the sandbox, albeit
>   they be on the same machine, will fail. See the next topic for
>   additional detail.

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox